# Combine two SQL queries of different date criteria

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I have a .NET project in VS 2010. I have some data and I want to show it in a local rdlc report.

I have data like the following:

[image: This is my Access database data]

I want show report like this:

[image: Report which I want]

In this report, the sum of total is between 02-01-2021 to 02-01-2021 or any other criteria.

And due = Sum of (a)-Sum of (b) grouped by custid between 01-01-2021 to 02-01-2021

That means I have two different queries with two different date criteria.

I tried using two datasets but my rdlc local report is not supporting lookup function.

I also tried `union` but it returns data in two rows, but I need data on a single row

I also tried different SQL query function but they have not worked for me.

If you have any solution, please help me.

- Database : MS Access
- VS 2010
- vb.net

Comment: Would an inner select work here?  select A as TOTAL, SUM(A) - SUM(B) as TOTAL_DUE from (SELECT SUM(A) as A, B from mytable GROUP BY CUSTNO) - something like that?

Comment: @June7 Who asked?

Comment: @Devyanilnfotech, I am not understanding the Due value of 1000 for CustID 1. Should it be 500?

Comment: @june7 you are right that's my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery:

```sql
SELECT 
    YourTable.CustNo, 
    (Select Top 1 T.[A] 
    From YourTable As T 
    Where T.CustNo = YourTable.CustNo 
    Order By T.Date Desc) AS Total, 
    Sum([A])-Sum([B]) AS [Total Due]
FROM 
    YourTable
GROUP BY 
    YourTable.CustNo;
```

Result, however, will be as noted by June:

[image]

Comment: Works for the sample data but I suspect will need some filter criteria for date ranges pulling from larger dataset. We really need a more representative data sample and more info about criteria.